# Multicollinearity problem and differencing time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multicollinearity

I have to estimate the regression equation by OLS and do in-sample forecasting of the time series. It has a trend and seasonal variations. So I try to estimate the model which looks like

$$\text{ln} Y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1t + \beta_1 \text{ln} X_t + \gamma_1 M_1 + \dots + \gamma_{11} M_{11} + \epsilon_t$$

Where $M_1$, $M_2$, etc. are dummy variables for months, $t$ is a linear time trend and $X_t$ is an independent variable.

When I run my model I have a multicollinearity problem: strong correlation between variables $t$ and $X_t$. And my question is the following: will it be correct to differentiate time series before running the model? Doing this I will be able to remove trend and in the same time I will keep my variable $X_t$.

Comment: Can you just abandon $X_{t}$? Obviously you have to keep $t$.

Comment: alternatively, keep $x_t$ but without taking logs.

Comment: if $x_t$ is almost linear in $t$, differentiating the series will remove $x_t$ as well.

Comment: @Bombyxmori, why is it obvious that $X_t$ rather than $t$ should be removed? Based on in-sample analysis we may not know which of the two determines $Y_t$, so it might as well be $X_t$ that is relevant. Subject-matter knowledge could help here since statistics might not be helpful in this setting.

Comment: @RichardHardy: The most obvious idea is to approximate $Y_{t}$ using a function of $t$ and some other predictor variables. $t$ is much easier to interpret than $X_{t}$. If one use OLS procedure and differentiate, than $\frac{d}{d?}\epsilon_{t}$ does not have a nice interpretation as $N(0,\sigma)$ variable anymore. In fact in OLS framework $X_{t}$s are considered as fixed and differentiating fixed values makes little sense.

Comment: @Bombyxmori, I don't think you have addressed the issue I raised. Meanwhile, regarding your current points: interpretation might or might not be easier with $t$ than with $X_t$, it depends entirely on the particular application. Also, errors need not be normally distributed; this is not a requirement for OLS to be consistent and MVUE. Also, I disagree with your last point; $X_t$ might be a random variable, that does not invalidate OLS. And in general, there are many economic applications where differencing makes perfect sense; would you criticize all of them by construction?

Comment: @RichardHardy: You can relax the requirement by letting $X_{t}$ be a random variable (say based on $t$) as well, but I do not think this is the point at here. The original OLS equation's differential may not be the same equation you get after you differentiate and carry out the least square fitting procedure. You would most likely get a new, different model this way. As I said, $t$ is much easier to interpret than $X_{t}$ (regardless of "the particular application" you are talking about). It does not make sense for $t$ to be dependent on $X_{t}$, but the other way around is much easier.

Comment: @Bombyxmori, let us agree to disagree. I hope this debate will add some insight into the problem.

Comment: @RichardHardy, Thank you for your help ! If $X_t$ has a linear trend (actually $Y_t$ has the same positive linear trend), is it correct to remove $t$ ?

Comment: I think Bombyx and I both missed an important point in the discussion above. If $Y_t$ has a linear trend, then $Y_t$ is nonstationary. If $X_t$ has a linear trend, too, excluding $t$ from the regressor set would be a bad idea. It would be something like running a regression of a unit-root variable on another unit-root variable; in that case there are stochastic trends that mess up the results. Meanwhile, in your case we deal with a deterministic trend, and it has to be accounted for by including $t$ or detrending the variables beforehand.